# I cannot get the stored values using chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use `chrome.storage` API to store and get back values in `content.js` of my Chrome extension, and I have already set the permission for storage in the `manifest.json` file. After using setStorage('test','123456') when I call `getStorage('test')` function I am getting `'Value for key is: undefined` in the console. Can you please help me figure out the problem?

```
function setStorage(key,value){
    chrome.storage.local.set({key: value}, function() {
    console.log('Value for '+key+' is set to ' + value);
});
```

```
function getStorage(key){
    chrome.storage.local.get([key], function(result) {
    console.log('Value for '+key+' is: ' + result.key);
});
}
```

Edit: I wrapped key in `getStorage()` as an array `[key]`.

Comment: Change `chrome.storage.local.set({key: value}, function(){` for `chrome.storage.local.set({[key]: value}, function(){`. In your function you are using the literal word "key" as the key, not the value of the `key`variable.

Comment: And then in the function `getStorage`, change `result.key` for `result[key]`, for the same reason.

Answer (score -1):

From the looks of the [Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#usage), when "`get`ting" the value, it looks like you need to wrap your key in an Array (aka List):

*Copied from docs*

```
chrome.storage.local.set({key: value}, function() {
  console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
});

chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
  console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
});
```

#### Sidenote

It may be better to use `chrome.storage.sync...` since it provides extra functionality to users with a Google account across multiple devices.
With that said, only non-confidential data should be saved in the `chrome.storage` object

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Could you provide a `console.log()` output of the steps being followed when calling your `setStorage` and `getStorage` functions?
What is the `typeof key`?

Have you declared the "storage" permission in the extension manifest?